# Convert Regex to Mask

Tags: code-golf, string, array, regular-expression, text-processing

*From [my CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59600689#59600689).*

Given a regex and a non-empty printable ASCII text, return one bit per character in the text, indicating the positions of beginnings of non-overlapping matches, and also the positions of beginnings of sequences that are not part of any non-overlapping matches.

You can:

- take the regex as a regex object, string or any other way that is reasonable or allowed by default rules
- take the text as a string object, character list, or any other way that is reasonable or allowed by default rules
- return the bits as an array, integer, or any other way that is reasonable or allowed by default rules

You may use any flavour, library, or implementation for regexes, as long as you support:

- any-character wildcards, e.g. `.`
- positive and negative character classes, e.g. `[ab]` and `[^ab]`
- repetitions, e.g. `a?` and `a+` and `a*` and/or the general `a{m,n}` form
- capturing groups, e.g. `(ab)`
- alternatives, e.g. `a|b`

### Examples

`[0123456789]+` or `[0123456789]{1,}`
`Hello4the42`
`10000110010`

`(aa)+` or `(aa){1,}`
`aaaaaaa`
`1000001`

`aaa`
`baaaab`
`110010`

`aaa|b`
`baaaab`
`110011`

`aab?` or `aab{0,1}`
`baaaab`
`110100`

`x.*z` or `x.{0,}z`
`abcdef`
`100000`

(you can take this as `(?:)` if necessary)
`Hello`
`11111`

`[^aeiou]+` or `[^aeiou]{1,}`
`Hello, world!`
`1110110011000`

`aaa`
`aaaaaaa`
`1001001`

`10101`
`101010101`
`100001000`

Comment: I think the last testcase is supposed to be `[^aeiou]+`, otherwise the output would be all 1's. And for the `aab?` case I get `b<aa><aab>` -> `1 1 0 1 0 0`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks. So much for doing them by hand.

Comment: What happens in situations where there is more-than-one way to assign non-overlapping matches?  Such as ```aaa``` inside ```aaaaaaa``` (possible outputs: ```1001001``` (back-to-back ```aaa``` matches, followed by a single ```a```), ```1001100``` (```aaa```,```a```,```aaa```) or ```1100100``` (```a```,```aaa```,```aaa```)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Regexes begin as early as possible and are greedy by default. I've added a test case to the effect.

Comment: "any other way that is reasonable or allowed by default rules, but you must support" ...?

Comment: @pxeger Right, you really do have to support. (Left over from when moving the list of required regex features into its own list.)

Comment: I might be being dense, but how does (aa)+ or (aa){1,} take aaaaaaa and give 1000001 rather than 1000000? The last character is not the start of a matching or non-matching sequence. It's just the last character of the first matching sequence, so feels like it should be 0. What'm I missing? Edit: Oh, even number of 'a's, ignore me :)

Comment: JavaScript RegExp object have some flags. For example, `"aa".match(/a/)` returns 1st match while `"aa".match(/a/g)` returns all matches. May I ask caller to specify / not specify certain flags? Or what is the default rule of these flags?

Comment: @tsh In JS, the flags are part of the regexp, so I think it is OK to for the caller to include them, but not for you to ask for them, so if the caller supplies `/a/` it'll only match once. E.g. `/a/` and `aaa` would give `110`

Comment: @Adám It a bit confusing. If so, should I assume all regex passed to my function includes `g` (global) flags? As they are what current testcases behavior.

Comment: @tsh What I mean to say is that the default for JS is that `g` is missing, so if you want, you can treat it as only matching once. However, if it works better for you, then it is fine to state that you only support regexps with `g` as that is what the challenge requires as a minimum. I just wanted to avoid "cheating" by asking the caller for further specific flags.

Comment: suggested test case: with `0`s and `1`s in the string to avoid flawed regex trickery

Comment: @MarcMush Good call. Added.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Assumes an index origin of 0.

```apl
{(⍳≢⍵)∊0,∊+\¨⍺⎕S 0 1⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUe/mR52LHvVu1XzU0WWgAyS0Yw6teNS761Hf1GAFAwXDR10g2dr/aY/aJjzq7QMKe/o/6mo@tN74UdtEkKIgZyAZ4uEZ/B8spwBUp2DApR5tYGhkbGJqZm5hGautrpCmoO6RmpOTb1KSkWpipM6lrpGYqAkUhwGgfCIEAOVApIICslwSSCYJIlWTpI5DKsleHbuuCj2tKlSpxKTklNQ0oBSyRRApsDuBMtFxiamZ@aWxUFfCZHQUyvOLclIU1QE)

`⍺⎕S 0 1⊢⍵`: **S**earch for matches of the regex `⍺` in the string `⍵`. For each each match return the number of characters before the match (0) and the length of the match (1).
`+\¨`: For each match, get the cumulative sums. This gives the 0-based starting index of the match and the first index after the match.
`∊`: Flatten into a single list of indices.
`0,`: Prepend a zero in case there was no match at the beginning.
`(⍳≢⍵)∊`: For each index of the string `⍵`, is it an element of this list?

Comment: Nice! Btw, Dyalog APL uses PCRE which handles the empty regex just fine.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```
~L$`^.*
0A`¶, ,S0`($&)
.
0
m`^.
1
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvr6d9aJuetn68hoZ7wv86H5WEOD0tLgPHhEPbdBR0gg0SNFTUNLn0uAy4coEyXIZch7Zx/f8fbWBoZGxiamZuYRmrzeWRmpOTb1KSkWpixKWRmKipzZUIASCaKwnESgIxa5IQnCR7GLtCT6uKKzEpOSU1jUtDE2IYV3RcYmpmfinMcB2F8vyinBRFAA) Link includes test suite which doesn't support empty regex, so `()` is used instead. Explanation:

```
L$`^.*
0A`¶, ,S0`($&)
```

Wrap the regex in a capturing group and prefix it with commands that delete the regex from the input and split the ASCII text on the regex, including only the first capturing group in the output. (This unfortunately still renumbers the other capturing groups. A similar problem applies to the `w` modifier in Retina itself, but at least Retina is able to avoid renumbering numbered capturing groups in that case.)

```
~`
```

Evaluate those commands on the original input.

```
.
0
```

Change all characters to `0`s.

```
m`^.
1
```

Change all characters at the beginning of lines to `1`s.

```
¶
```

Join everything back together.

Comment: All regex to deal with regex. Gotta love it!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 77 bytes

```r
function(p,t,m=el(gregexpr(p,t))){T[c(m,m+attr(m,"m"))[m>0]]=1;T[1:nchar(t)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc7LDoIwEAXQvV9B6qajjRHFd3DtB7BriGlLERJaSBkT4@Pb0crex6xuJudmxnVGoCqOtrZ9aFE4PJY2K5Vu4y4/W4VlbWnDkJlYV/Tk9ElfGuc3AHBLuKKGmbFAdK9ADAHgZj9N0zjcJTzcWlUIRxHSx8dblPBpOJtHi@VqvUnHhJGDrqo6wkJHMwKDz10qBPiO6Oer94YR6a38Bd/lX/yPTy6T0dVzqTKdEwiGga2Dtxx0Tw)

Outputs `1` for starts of matches/non-matches, `NA` otherwise.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> <s>86</s> 84 bytes

*Edit: thanks to pajonk for spotting a bug when there is no match*

```r
function(p,t,l=0:nchar(t),m=el(gregexpr(p,t)))`[<-`(!l,c(m,m+attr(m,"m"))[m>0],1)[l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc5NDoIwEAXgvafAuuloNYD4G3HtHQjRUquQtIWUMSHGu6OVPcqsXjLfy4xtNUeRn01pulAjt3guzLUQso7b28MILEpDK4ZMxf7eiJxbisB0LBW9W3mXTWXdGgAuyWF@oWPFBNVMzzii/QSiCUCij37KAkhU2nuSksQPwmW0Wm@2u3RGGDlJpcoIcxmFBEb9Xco5uA7v5qd3hpHM2ewf/MoG8QGfNIvp0/FMXOWNgDfxTOl95ah9Aw)

Outputs `1`/`0`.

```r
function(p,t,           # p = pattern, t = text,
 m=el(gregexpr(p,t)))   # m = positions of matches,
                        # with attribute "match.length" = lengths of matches
                        # (can be abbreviated as "m");
 head(...,-1)           # Return all except the last element of...                       
 `[<-`(                 # assigning the elements of...
 !0:nchar(t)            # ...a vector of 1 followed by nchar(t) zeros...
 c(m,                   # at the positions of the matches, 
     m+attr(m,"m")      # and the positions immediately after the matches,
  )[m>0]                # (but ignoring the value of -1 assigned to 'no match')...
 ,1)                    # ...to 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>86</strike>, 79 bytes

```python
lambda r,s:(c:=1<<len(s)-1)|sum({c>>j for i in r.finditer(s)for j in i.span()})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBRb4IwEMff@yk6ntqtI9S5zRHR1z0b39QlBUqsgUJKzRzIZ2c90Omapr3@7n/Xu6t@7L7UL7PK9Fm07XNRxKnAhtUhScKIz@e51KSmz5ye62NB2mSxOOCsNFhhpbHxM6VTZaVxGqAHoMqvK6EJ7Wi/jjzP2wR88jJ9fXuffeyesFPdg5azDn3KPC@ndi@nE8QDt7g7eYAQEYIOIWAMUjGuURZwBADFgGJ0jXKPc/wPDrp4CZnc3QaMd3d@p0Do5D824D/5zt01SMRJKrPLP66SZUjHOl0Eh4SbLyFVeby0dHnc2mH4uzR5@gDysR8@JIJ675qA7WbkRpYrS7yt3mqPIlVUpbHYSLSONhtz9cJP3jBoA4O2tyiP7gBbwOsdAnvFSM0oI4LRgYYINwxHuM2IkX5SFpXKJTGU1RT/pVx1CFdGaUsa1kQRGIJNKO1/AQ)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##VZBRb4IwEMff@ym6PrVbR6hzmyOir3s2vqlLCpRYA4UUzBzIZ2c90Omapr3@7n/Xuyt/6n1hXmal7dNw22cyjxKJLa@ClLQ0DkIxn2fK0Io9C3aujjlt48XigNPCYo21wdZLtUl0razTAD0A1V5VSkNZx4KoI/06JIRsfDF5mb6@vc8@dk/YKe9BK3iHPlWWFdN6r6YTJHy3hDuFjxCVkg0hYAxSOa5R5gsEAEWAInSNco9z9A8OumgJmdzd@lx0d36nQOjkPTbgP3nO3TVIRnGi0ss/rpJlwMY6XYSAhJsvqXRxvLR0edza4fi7sFnyAPKxHzEkgnrvmoDtZuTGlumakq3ZGsKQzsvC1tgqtA43G3v1wk9kGLaFYde3KMJ2gGvA6x0Ce8VpxRmnkrOBBgg3HIe4TalVXlzkpc4UtYxXDP@lXHUIl1abmja8CUPJ@l8)

Takes a re object and a string and returns <strike>a string of 1s and 0s</strike> an integer that encodes the mask in binary.

Output is created by bitwise arithmetic. As we know the leftmost bit is set there are no worries about leading zeros. Ideally, we would like to `or`-reduce the set bits. As there is no short way to do this (is there?) we instead take the sum after eliminating any duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```ruby
f=->r,s,a=0{s>''?[(a=((s=~r)!=0?a-1:[a-1,s[r].size].max))>0,*f[r,s[1..-1],a]]:[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBDsIgEEDRq9RuCmagoF2RAAeZzIKqJC5MGogJ2tarY9m8/M1P7/lTa7TCJcgQrFqzGwaPLFjGsv0lfrLKB6ENHkDGRDI/vw@Sr1A4dwrOEY8VtZRCEwQig7TXpYs46st1GqEPc4vbvdm3cVm3spXOa6P2@gc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 87 bytes

```
def f(s,p):
 r=[i:=0]
 for m in p.finditer(s):r+=m.span()
 for x in s:yield i in r;i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY87DsIwEET7nGJxZZMQQYeMXNBxA4ooSCG2YZF_2hgBZ6GhgTtxGxQB5Uhv3mjur3TLxxgej-c529nyvdXGguVDlYQsgFSDUs3bAmwk8IABUm0xaMyG-CAklcrXQ-oCF1_mOjKDvKFxGnAMtMJSLX56e1Cu83vdTdcyEYbMGatPEQNn8wVr-nZ09GPN8ulaCFGgT5EykCkOnG2Mc7GCSySnJ6wiU_fRJ3SGE2t2ncF4bksmxHftf-oD)

Takes a string and an [`re.Pattern` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects), and returns a generator of booleans.

I'm really not happy with the last line; it seems like there must be a better way of doing it.

---

Explanation:

- `i:=0`: using the observation that the first bit is always set, we can abuse the initial definition of `r` to initialise `i` to `0` at the same time
- `for m in p.finditer(s):`: for every (non-overlapping) match of `p` inside `s`:

  - `r+=m.span()`: append the range of the match object - inclusive start, exclusive end. This is convenient, because we need to include a `1` for the start of every match, and after the end of every match.
    If two matches are consecutive, this is not a problem, because it doesn't matter if the same value is added to the list twice (once for the end of the first, and once for the start of the second).
- Finally, output a generator of booleans for each index in the string's range according to whether that index is in the list `r`.

If a match occurs at the end of the string, an out-of-bounds index will be appended to `r`, but this also doesn't matter, because we only check indeces in `s`'s range.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 43 bytes

```
s1{g1~&l_j}{g1~=}w!ClFL`Fz?{L['0j.*'10sa}\m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TVxD3v9iwOt2wTi0nPqsWxLCtLVd0znHzSXCrsq/2iVY3yNLTUjc0KE6sjcn9/z/awNDI2MTUzNzCMlabyyM1JyffpCQj1cQIAA)

```
s1       # Set 1 to be the RegEx
{g1      # Get the RegEx
 ~&      # Partition based on the RegEx (PreMatch, Match, PostMatch)
 l_j     # Get PostMatch out of block and on top of the stack
}
{
 g1~=    # PostMatch still contains match to RegEx
}w!      # While
ClFL     # Collect results and flatten
`Fz?     # Remove empty string(s)
{
 L[      # Length
 '0j.*   # "0"*Len
 '1 0 sa # Set first char to 1
}\m      # Map and concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 84 bytes

```javascript
s=>r=>[...s].map((_,i)=>s.replace(r,(...p)=>i=(v=p.at(-2)-i)&&v+p[0].length&&i)&&!i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLfT9swEMefl7/iKqTWpq2TlO4HdClCvGzT0HjgreomJ3USM9eOHCfQDf72zk6K1ELFqBXZyt35c1/f3S2taZloXpihVAu29o87HhzDtVCrlAsBKoULrenqiBpItVo6Z25MUZ75fsZNXsUkUUvfJCenfqFVoUoqhpoJanjNhlwu2D2X2XDJTK4WR4USDdZRLlWx0jzLDaAEwygYBXBDY7gwv7ks4ZsmLujq6w185wmTJbO/vvcjvmWJIQuWcsmubT6mzQo1ColNb5RZFWwAPWp6A/jrAdRUVOwM0komhisJ1CCJrecdgIQIrqjJidHW68wPDxBMnIungCR8hgDbqH4EJuclEUxmJt/1uysSpjsRGDQzlZZQyVbnormzMbrAmZxPrLbHgd3uNDc0FlajlcGchclqyXRrS6koG2OiZMqzSm@HPuKJ56XRuoymOprOCCHlnCxpgdCvAcfRtCSaFYImDOkBst7C2niE6qggtgzDER5y3O3W/WIWzDfau11n6nC8tglLJRgRKkMp6n1hQqixydl41MPInwXh6GT8/sPHT6fzvp/hJm0N0RT6NSa3ikvU62E8Ad@HMLArtHsYeM@otF2OiCjFr5K21xM1CJ8TY8eLHdCeb8VtiHsl7gAf4jcjn4CvKozP3y6xBVrkiyLGiZ0zB7wnx38OAzZF9Pb1uunJ@Rk@tIbhyxc3vAHcKS0WnWZ6flLGVTX/T79bXjs64R6dW9NzULPbh7tv/Q8)

- `Array#at` is ES2022.

Could be [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZLfT9swEMefl7/iKqTWpqmTFPaDdilCvGzT0HjgDXWTkzqJmWtHjhPoVv72zk6KRKFicIoc@e78ua99d0MbWqWal2Yk1YJtgsOeB4dwKdQq40KAyuBMa7o6oAYyrZYuWBhTVpMgyLkp6oSkahmY9OgkKLUqVUXFSDNBDW/YiMsFu@MyHy2ZKdTioFSixTrKuSpXmueFAZRiGIfjEK5oAmfmN5cVfNPEJV18vYLvPGWyYnYbeD@SG5YasmAZl@zS1mParFCrkNjyRplVyXwYUDPw4a8H0FBRswlktUwNVxKoQRLbyDsACTFcUFMQo23UuddrCKcuxDNAEj5DiG3WMAZT8IoIJnNT7MbdEQmznQwMmplaS6hlp3PRntk6XeK1nE@ttnvfLreaG5oIq9HKYM7DZL1kuvNlVFStM1Uy43mtH6fe46nnZfGmimc6nl0TQqo5WdISoV8@x/GsIpqVgqYMaR9RP7EuHqMmTkYc9/vNkG4F9/tu3@N4Y6tUSjAiVI4yNPjChFDHpmDH4wFGwXUYjY@O33/4@OlkPgxy3NZqIJ7BsMHkRnGJBgOMpxAEEIXWIrtGofeESjtzRHQ6oRS/yHpsD9wwespMHDFxSPt/LW5L3CtyB7hOXo18AL6oMDl9vcQOaJHPnjFJ7Xg54B05/PM2YPuI3r5ub7uC3/qG0fMbtzwfbpUWi147Pz8p46qe/6ffHa8bnmiPzkfz86Zmdxd33@Yf) if regex passed to this function use `(?:aa)` instead of `(aa)`.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) + [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js), 78 bytes

```javascript
s=>r=>[...s].map((_,i)=>s.matchAll(`(${r})|((?!${r}).)+`).some(v=>v.index==i))
```

- `String#matchAll` is ES2020.
- [`Iterator#some`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) is currently Stage 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.3](http://julialang.org/), 73 bytes

```julia
a\b=(r=[0;b...].==0;findall(a,b).|>m->r[m.start]=r[m.stop+1]=1;pop!(r);r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHRTtswFIbv/RQuSCiBkMS0sC1VYENCGhO7YdtV1kl247Qurh05DoRRnmMPtAdjx04LreaLxOc//znns71opaCke9nHX9wOk3gY4a/X37EUU66mHO3jubV1kyXJTNh5y@KpXibee0PVLFm4XcKkZsk91MYkYbThieEz3sULuX8zHI2Ob4anZwhVrZpaoRW@BEdcCVVSKQObZT8UqE@fWGMNndpv1gg1i25dh@cIN1m2mxljfc@NpHWWXWot84rKhocIw6p0q0qcY2hob4GOP10r@1xMfFJEmEOuEqaxMJt3QRNGWNK3yNse5kJybE3LfeiW8WWqVLyzgQWkCItwO5vnWGk7Bzh8cICZ4fTuNV23zXwQeLIIm7eyBTRdHwSvVlg0fFnbx8CE@KJndNvM8wU7ZedwjP@mfBSKuRENFtDXgQJvAKCLvpSr0v8Nt61R/UUhEF/oT5YHJi/SMYvjeBLneTrePA2NWBivzpfH56ZYxo2lxk7yfqvrIzLJybjW9QDwxiZ8MTkQlVIo3gQhqrQBFKHwHX9swFGQbJTBwP4tKED6Bw5MISY9IgMNIujbE3f1WjjphRoe30oVBCyiYbg@TQMeOMJWtNBCBeQQgnCn7FUQlXcOcjfi7ZnWtr2/f/BVV/Op5WWG9yJn2r3CjTP091ek5GQ4Oj179/7D5Ah95lLqkZ3z0QkiKSwCX5IiFFAaHiHarz6VEuQExJzE0MYJwYrtiN7HLrY0UBHq4sPfiLJpyat1Q4R6ALAQV1X8olzodsMV4QdtZDlw6R6M@CIHsUVGPJkbQvrvepf6VPoP)

- `findall(::Regex,::String)` was added in Julia 1.3 and returns a vector of ranges for each match.
- `pop!(r);r` is one byte shorter than `r[1:end-1]`
- expects `a` as a `Regex` object and `b` a `String`
- output is a vector of `Bool`s